# Reordering Mysql query results

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following mysql query where Id is the primary key auto incremented starting from 1,2...to 450 etc.

```
$query = "SELECT Id, PromA, PromB, PromC FROM Promtab Order by Id DESC Limit 200"; 
$aresult = $con->query($query);
```

and the following PHP snippet:

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)){
    echo "[".$row["Id"].", ".$row["PromA"].",".$row["PromB"].",".$row["PromC"]."],";
}
?>
```

When I use the current query and php code I get the results (`Id` and `Data` `DESC order`) :

```
    Id,  PromA, PromB, PromC
    450   230    220    200
    449   150    140    180
    448   221    70     145
    .
    .
    1     120    110    105
```

What I need is this (ONLY `Id ASC order`, Data order doesn't change) :

```
    Id,  PromA, PromB, PromC
     1   230    220    200
     2   150    140    180
     3   221    70     145
     .
     .
    450    120    110    105
```

How can I do this simply?

Thanks.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: "Data order doesn't change" .... ummmm, wha??  You want to see data that doesn't correspond to the ID listed next to it?

Comment: The data is associated with the Id so if you change the sort order of the Id the data is going to change too.

Comment: Are you really saying you want the `Id` column sorted ASC but the other columns to stay in DESC order? **Thats makes no sense** So I must be missing something

Comment: I just need to reverse the Id. I want to get the latest results but with the id starting from 1,2,3 etc. every time.

Comment: i believe the topicstarter wants to simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` or ranking for the ID column.. what makes the most sense

Comment: yes, I am open for a workaround solution too.

Comment: So then you don't actually want the ID, you just want to display a counter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Phew, now that makes sense

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind? Because what you ask has no logic (since the id is link to the other data) so you just want to display your data as you already did and replace the id of each row by a counter from 1 to 200?

Comment: yes, it is not very logical, but i need to use the data somewhere else, and I needed the id from 1 with latest results for this.

Comment: "i believe the topicstarter wants to simulate ROW_NUMBER() or ranking for the ID column.. what makes the most sense" i was thinking if i made the comment i also post an answer on how to simulate `ROW_NUMBER()` in MySQL version under MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to see the actual IDs against rows, but simply the numerical sequential numbers from 1 to 200 (you have `LIMIT 200`).  In this case what you can do is something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT PromA, PromB, PromC FROM Promtab Order by Id DESC Limit 200"; 
$aresult = $con->query($query);

$id = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)) {
    echo "[" . ($id++) . ", {$row['PromA']}, {$row['PromB']}, {$row['PromC']}]";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a simple inline variable within the sql ( similar to that shown above by @Raymond )

```
select ( @var := ifnull( @var, 0 ) + 1 ) as `row`, `id`, `proma`,`promb`,`promc` 
from `promtab` 
order by `id` desc;
```

One thing to note with this approach is the value of `@var` is maintained at the end of the query so subsequent queries would continue to increment the value. To negate that you would set the value to null after running the initial query - ie `set @var=null;`

If the end usage of the query is a simple display in HTML a css variable might be the simplest option and would not require any additional mods to the base sql query.

Comment: "One thing to note with this ... to increment the value" i was always under the believe the user variable with SET was session shared.. And a variable you set within a query is stored for query execution only.. So i wanted to this see it for myself this sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/340e01/438 confirms what you said is how MySQL handles MySQL user variables +1 for learning me something new. Besides it's also in the manual i notice now "User-defined variables are session specific" geus i missed that line before.

Answer (score 2):

You can get id data and other data separately And then display them at the same time

```
$queryForId = "SELECT Id FROM Promtab Order by Id ASC Limit 200"; 
$queryForData = "SELECT PromA, PromB, PromC FROM Promtab Order by Id DESC Limit 200";
$resultForId = $con->query($queryForId);
$resultForData = $con->query($queryForData);
```

and the php part as:

```
<?php
while($rowId = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultForId)){
  $rowData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultForData);
echo "[".$rowForId["Id"].", ".$rowForData["PromA"].",".$rowForData["PromB"].",".$rowForData["PromC"]."],";
}
?>
```

Comment: You can do this, but it seems completely illogical to me.

Comment: But what if the data in id is not in sequence

Comment: Then this makes even less sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MySQL's user variables to simulate`ROW_NUMBER()` under MySQL versions under MySQL 8.0. 
you need atleast MySQL 5.0.51b to be able to use MySQL's user variables.

```
SELECT 
   (@ROW_NUMBER := @ROW_NUMBER + 1) AS Id
 , Promtab_ordered.* 
FROM (
  SELECT
      Promtab.PromA
    , Promtab.PromB
    , Promtab.PromC
   FROM
     Promtab
   ORDER BY
    Promtab.Id DESC
   LIMIT 200
) AS Promtab_ordered
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @ROW_NUMBER := 0 ) AS init_user_param
ORDER BY 
 Id ASC
```

Comment: MySQL's user variables have been available since at least 5.0.51b, and note that there should really be another ORDER BY here.

Comment: "MySQL's user variables have been available since at least 5.0.51b" Problem is that the MySQL docs under version 5.6 isn't really easy accessible annymore on the official MySQL website so i didn't search for a minimal required version to use MySQL's user variables but thanks @Strawberry and you are right about the extra `ORDER BY`

Comment: It also highlights how out of date my version of MySQL is :-(

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you are effectively seperating the order displayed from the order that comes from the database.

If that's the case, and since that you are returning the results as an array, you can iterate the results something in the lines of (not tested):

```
$resultsArray = mysqli_fetch_array($aresult));
for($i = 0; $i <= count($resultsArray); $i){
    // $i will be your index. Your query will return the results descending
}
```

hope it helps